# En esta oración ¿cuáles son las funciones sintácticas?

Tags: sintaxis

> No tienes derecho a afearles que hayan incumplido todas sus promesas electorales

Identifico "tienes" como el núcleo del predicado (el verbo principal de la oración principal) y "derecho" como COD. Pero ya estoy atascado.. "a afearles..." ¿funcióna como complemento preposicional o COI?

También no estoy seguro de donde comienza la oración subordinada, o si hay varias.
Al principio identifico "que hayan incumplido todas sus promesas electorales" como una oración subordinada sustantiva, pero ya no estoy seguro. ¿Y qué función desempeña?

Cualquier ayuda es muy apreciada.

Answer (score 2):

Tengo la gramática más que olvidada, pero mirando un poco he encontrado el [complemento de régimen verbal o suplemento](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_de_r%C3%A9gimen). Creo que "a afearles..." entra en esa categoría:

> La preposición que lo introduce puede ser cualquiera, incluso *a*. Se
>   reconoce porque es conmutable o sustituible por dicha preposición más
>   pronombre tónico:
>
> - Cuento *con Luisa* = Cuento con ella.
> - Me acuerdo *de Pedro* = Me acuerdo de él.
> - El perro cuida *de la casa* = El perro cuida de ella.
> - Me acuerdo *de ese viaje* = Me acuerdo de eso.

En este caso, podemos hacer:

> No tienes derecho a **afearles [...]** = No tienes derecho a **eso**

Respecto a la oración subordinada, creo que tienes razón en que es una [oración subordinada sustantiva](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oraci%C3%B3n_subordinada#Subordinaci.C3.B3n_sustantiva):

> Las proposiciones subordinadas sustantivas se dejan sustituir por un
>   pronombre neutro: eso, esto etcétera, o por un infinitivo menos
>   frecuentemente.

Así, en el caso que nos ocupa, podríamos sustituir "que hayan incumplido [...]" por "eso":

> [...] afearles **que hayan incumplido [...]** = [...] afearles **eso**

Concretando un poco más, diría que es una oración subordinada sustantiva en función de objeto directo.

Answer (score 1):

"Derecho a afearles" es un Sintagma Nominal que funciona como Complemento Directo de "tienes". "A afearles" es un Sintagma Preposicional complemento de "derecho". "Afearles" es una sustantiva término de la preposición "a".